# find the occurrences of particular string in give string?

Tags: regex, perl

hi friends now 'm working in perl i need to check the give string occurence in a set of array using perl!i tried lot but i can't can anybody?

```
open FILE, "<", "tab_name.txt" or die $!;
my @tabName=<FILE>;
my @all_files= <*>;
foreach my $tab(@tabName){

    $_=$tab;
    my $pgr="PGR Usage";
    if(m/$pgr/)
    {

        for(my $t=0;scalar @all_files;$t++){
            my $file_name='PGR.csv';            
            $_=$all_files[$t];          
            if(m\$file_name\)
            {

                print $file_name;           
            }           
        }

        print "\n$tab\n";   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
for(my $t=0;scalar @all_files;$t++){
```

The second part of the for loop needs to be a condition, such as:

```
for(my $t=0;$t < @all_files;$t++){
```

Your code as written will never end.

However, this is much better:

```
foreach (@all_files){
```

In addition, you have a problem with your regex. A variable in a regex is treated as a regular expression. `.` is a special character matching anything.  Thus, your code would match `PGR.csv`, but also `PGRacsv`, etc.  And it would also match filenames where that is a part of the name, such as `FOO_PGR.csvblah`.  To solve this:

- Use quote literal (`\Q...\E`) to make sure the filename is treated literally.
- Use anchors to match the beginning and end of the string (`^`, `$`).

Also, backslashes are valid, but they are a strange character to use.

The corrected regex looks like this:

```
   m/^\Q$file_name\E$/
```

Also, you should put this at the top of every script you write:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
for(my $t=0;scalar @all_files;$t++){
```

produces an infinite loop, you'd better use:

```
for(my $t=0;$t < @all_files;$t++){
```

Comment: how to use regular expression in perl?

Comment: when i tried the above script if(m/$pgr/) this works but second inner condition is not working always else block only execute dude

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the problems you have going through the array, are you looking for [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)?